WordPress multisite redirect from Mainpage to Sub Page
I have a WordPress multisite setup. Now I want a redirect from the Main Page www.mypage.com to www.mypage.com/CH-DE. it should work with mypage.com, www.mypage.com, https://wwwmypage.com.

Sorry, but "I want" is not a question. And it is not something you tried to implement where we might help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
